# Special characters replaced by ? using SqlBulkCopy in c# from iSeries ODBC source

Tags: c#, character-encoding, odbc, sqlbulkcopy

I have some c# code that uses SqlBulkCopy to read data from a ODBC source using the iSeries Access ODBC Driver. I'm having a problem whereby some special characters (for example the Euro symbol €) are stored in sql as ?. The data is stored in the AS400 as CHAR datatype with a CCSID of 37.

I can get the correct characters to return in a console app by reading each value, and running each value through code like below:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(value);
byte[] uniBytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.Unicode, bytes);
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(uniBytes).Replace("\0",String.Empty));
```

Rather than re-writing the code so that it reads and converts every value, is there a solution that would still allow us to use the SqlBulkCopy?

Comment: How do you know the value isn't in sql correctly and it's just your viewer that can't handle the character?

Comment: SSMS can correctly display the character, and does if I insert he character manually. I've also used the ASCII function to confirm it's stored as ?.

Comment: create a view over the iseries table with the CCSID specified for each column that is not translating correctly. I think CCSID is 819 or 367.  Pull from the view.